# How is path interpreted when using SIRD in Play framework

Tags: playframework-2.3

The following example is from Play's documentation

To use the routing DSL in conjunction with a regular Play project that uses a routes file and controllers, extend the SimpleRouter:

```
package api

import javax.inject.Inject

import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.routing.Router.Routes
import play.api.routing.SimpleRouter
import play.api.routing.sird._

class ApiRouter @Inject()(controller: ApiController)
  extends SimpleRouter
{
  override def routes: Routes = {
    case GET(p"/") => controller.index
  }
}
```

Add the following line to conf/routes:

```
->      /api                        api.ApiRouter
```

**Question** - In the above example As `/api` already maps to `ApiRouter`, does `GET(p"/")` resolve to `somedomain.com/api/` or `somedomain.com/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will resolve to `somedomain.com/api/`, that is the main idea of the SIRD - it allows you to modularize routers.